# How to access data of nested objects in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, json, linkedhashmap

Data present in LinkedHashMap:-

```
{
    contacts={
        id={
            version=6,
            lastUpdatedTimeStamp=1377,
            contactID=23,
            firstName=B,
            lastName=K
        }
    }
}
```

Here, "contacts" & "id" are objects.

I am able to get the values of "contacts" :

```
LinkedHashMap map = restClient.getLinkedHashMap();
Object contactObj = map.get("contacts");
```

But how to get the value of "firstName"?

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: First share your contacts and id classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast the contactObj to the class whose primitive you want to access. Ex, if your class for contactObj is `Contact`, then you should do:

```
Contact contactObj = (Contact) map.get("contacts");
```

and then you can access the methods/primitives in the class that are accessible from this point. Ex, say your class is like

```
Class Contact{
String firstname;
public String getFirstName(){
  return this.firstname;
   }
}
```

So, you can access the first name like as shown below:

```
contactObj.getFirstName();
```